# HTML fail to load an array / Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I use woocommerce api to load subcategories on new page, from parent categories with ionic3. I do can get the subcategories but my problem is the when I'm trying to show my subcategories I got an error like in the screen below:

[image: consle log error]

and this is my sub.ts file code:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-subcategories',
  templateUrl: 'subcategories.html',
})
export class SubcategoriesPage {
  WooCommerce: any;
  page: number;
  categories: any = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public toastCtrl: ToastController, public ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.categories = this.navParams.get('category');

    this.WooCommerce = WC({
      url: "http:///",
      consumerKey: "///",
      consumerSecret:"///",
      wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
      queryStringAuth: true,
      verifySsl: true,
      version: 'wc/v3' 
    });

    this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products/categories?parent=" + this.categories.id).then((data) => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
       this.categories = JSON.parse(data.body);
     })


    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
  }
```

and my sub.HTML file code is :

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let sub of categories">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" item-left large></ion-icon>
      <h2> {‌{ sub.name }} </h2>
    </ion-item>
 </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

and when I select the parent category to display the subcategory I get an array of subcategories like in the screen below:
[image: array of subcategories]

Is there any suggestion edit.

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate the array key

```
@foreach (@yourcontainerData as $k=>$data)
{{$data.name}}
@endforeach
```

Here you are not iterating, in all cases if you tri access the first element then
    {{yourcontainerData[0].name}}

Comment: can you please explain that in another way

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring this way instead:

```
categories: any[] = [];
```

Comment: If I declare the array of categories in this way the parent id will be a conflict which will not lead me to the main category

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding

```
subcategories: any[] = [];
```

and then load my categories in the subcategories like

```
 this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.categories = JSON.parse(data.body);
         this.subcategories = this.categories
        console.log(this.subcategories );
     })
```